# Formatting K, M within SSRS Charts

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, reportbuilder3.0

I am trying to add formatting for K, M for the chart.

```
=IIF(Sum(Fields!orderedqty.Value * Fields!new_price.Value, "capexPO") >=1000000 , "'€' #,0,,"+"m",
IIF (Sum(Fields!orderedqty.Value * Fields!new_price.Value, "capexPO") >=1000, "'€' #,0,"+"k",
IIF (Sum(Fields!orderedqty.Value * Fields!new_price.Value, "capexPO") >=0," '€' 0",
IIF (Sum(Fields!orderedqty.Value * Fields!new_price.Value, "capexPO") <-1000000, "'€' #,0,,"+"m",
IIF (Sum(Fields!orderedqty.Value * Fields!new_price.Value, "capexPO") <-1000, "'€' #,0,"+"k", "0"
)
)
)
)
)
```

However, this does not work for values such as 1455537.13. In this case it displays $0M.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to format the axis? I think this is meant for a text box.

Comment: You should be able to change the Data Type in your report to a Number and then lop off the Decimals by changing it from 2-> 0. Have you tried this?

Comment: @Geo - I think the OP wants to scale an axis in thousands or millions based on the total (which should be in the format of `"'$'0,.00k;('$'0,.00k)"` or `"'$'0,,.00m;('$'0,,.00)m"` ).

Comment: Nope this is for the axis.